# Edit CustomViewGroup (RelativeLayout) after show (Android)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, viewgroup

I have a custom ViewGroup (RelativeLayout) with a ProgressBar and a TextView.
I want to show the progressBar some time, and then hide and show the Views inside my content.

CustomRelative

public class RelativeProgressNew extends RelativeLayout  {

```
ProgressBar progressBar;
TextView txtEmptyData;

Activity activity;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
View v;


public RelativeProgressNew(Context context, String text) {
    super(context);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}


public RelativeProgressNew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}

public RelativeProgressNew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom, this, true);
    txtEmptyData = v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmptyData);
    progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
}

private void finish(String text) {
    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_custom, this, true);
    txtEmptyData = v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmptyData);
    progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    txtEmptyData.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    txtEmptyData.setText(text);
}

public void finishValidData() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    txtEmptyData.setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

Layout Custom

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/linearProgress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmptyData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:text="EJEMPLO"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In my fragment layout I have this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.yustapps.agenda_novecientos.arq.RelativeProgressNew
        android:id="@+id/relativeProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/window_background"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="EXAMPLE"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.yustapps.agenda_novecientos.arq.RelativeProgressNew>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment

```
public class Inicio extends Fragment implements ConstantsInterface {
View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

        relativeProgress = new RelativeProgressNew(getActivity(), ConstantsInterface.EMPTY);
        simulateLoading();
    return v; 
}

 private void simulateLoading() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            relativeProgress.finish();


        }
    }.execute();
    }
```

}

And then how can I do? When I show the view in fragment, works correctly, but then I want to hide the progressBar and the fragment does not update.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Can you add the java code of the fragment?

Comment: Done. Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found your issue. You are creating a new `RelativeProgressNew` instance in `onCreateView`. What you should do however is: `(RelativeProgressNew)v.findViewById(R.id.relativeProgress)`.

So you have: `relativeProgress = (RelativeProgressNew)v.findViewById(R.id.relativeProgress);`

Also in your `RelativeProgressNew` inside your `finish(String text)` function do not re-inflate your Views. This should only happen once and you already do it inside the `init()` function (this has nothing to do with your issue but it improves your code)

Comment: I copied and pasted your RelativeProgressNew code and it works fine for me. If you still have your exception, could you post the log?